# How to fetch all objects AND their related objects AND filter by a related objects properties?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I tried two methods.

loadAll allows fetching of all objects AND their related objects are attached as well but does not allow me to filter by a property of a related object (I believe as I cannot work out how).

Secondly, I thought maybe this query would return all the related entities but does not.

```
MATCH (n:`MMLBusiness`) WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN n
```

Cannot work out how to fetch all objects AND their related objects (which loadAll does) attached AND filter by a related objects properties (which loadAll does not seem to allow me to do)?

Filtering means I wish to filter the properties of the related objects, not the MMLBusiness.

---

For a solution I'm going to do it in two steps, first I'm going to query to fetch all ID's by normal NEO4J Query then I'm going to fetch all those objects with those ID's.

Comment: There is no `queryAll` method on ogm Session, there is either `query`, `load` or  `loadAll`. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: You're returning the wrong thing. `n` is your start node, `m` will match to your start node and all immediately connected nodes. As far as filtering goes, can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: frant.hartm Yes your right, I mean't to say loadAll, I correct the question, secondly InverseFalcon when I return m using Neo4J OGM it didn't return Java classes

Comment: secondly InverseFalcon when I return p (NOT m) using Neo4J OGM it didn't return Java classes, when I return m I don't get my object with the other object attached, I just get all the objects not attached to each other